# Definition of dense sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know the following definition : a set $A$ is dense in a metric space $X$ if every point of $X$ is a closure point of $A$. That is, for every $x\in X$, every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$.

However, a book I read said this :

> A subset $S$ of $\Bbb R$ is dense if every point of $\Bbb R$ is a limit point (cluster point) of $S$ i.e. $S'=\Bbb R$.

This confused me. I know that $\overline D=X$ does not necessarily mean that $D'=X$. For example, let $X=[1,2]\cup${$3$} and $D=(1,2)\cup${$3$}. Then $\overline D=X$ but $D'=[1,2]≠X$. According to the definition I know $D$ is dense in $X$. But if I apply the latter definition (taking $X$ in place of $\Bbb R$) then it is not dense in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every point of $\mathbb R$ is a limit point of $S$ then indeed $S$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R$.

But the opposite of this is not true in general (so do not read it as a definition).

If e.g. $\mathbb R$ is equipped with discrete topology and $S=\mathbb R$ then $S$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R$.

However, in this case $S'=\varnothing$.

Comment: $S'=\Bbb R => \overline S=\Bbb R$. Is the converse true with the usual metric in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: If $\mathbb R$ is equipped with usual topology then the inverse is true. If $x\in\overline{S}$ then for every $n\in\mathbb N$ the set $B(x,\frac1n)$ must contain an element of $S$. If for some $n$ we have $B(x,\frac1n)\cap S=\{x\}$ then the other elements of $B(x,\frac1n)$ will not belong to $\overline S$, so that $S$ is not dense. So we conclude that $B(x,\frac1n)\cap S$ is a non-empty set that contains elements that differ from $x$.